# I can't create an SQL table due to a syntax error

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I try to create a table within my local SQL database. I followed a tutorial and ended up with a syntax error. I checked several similar stackoverflow threads and the solution was to remove reserved words...but in my code I can't find a reserved one neither.

Where is the problem in my code?

```
create table teams (
    team_id int(11) not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar() not null,
    logo varchar() not null,
    founded int(4) not null,
    venue_capacity int(6) not null,
    squad_value int(5) not null,
    total_national_trophies int(3) not null
);
```

Error Message:

```
#1064 - Fehler in der SQL-Syntax. Bitte die korrekte Syntax im Handbuch nachschlagen bei ') not null,
    logo varchar() not null,
    founded int(4) not null,
    ven' in Zeile 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a size for your `VARCHAR` columns, e.g. `VARCHAR(255)`.

The size indicates the maximum number of characters (not bytes) that can be inserted into the column.

The rewritten statement could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE teams (
    team_id INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    logo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    founded INT(4) NOT NULL,
    venue_capacity INT(6) NOT NULL,
    squad_value INT(5) NOT NULL,
    total_national_trophies INT(3) NOT NULL
);
```

---

<sup>* I prefer to uppercase my SQL keywords. It's just a matter of preference, and makes absolutely no difference in execution.</sup>

Comment: ...thank you, it worked. Will accept answer asap. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be this:

```
create table teams (
    team_id int(11) not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    logo varchar(255) not null,
    founded int(4) not null,
    venue_capacity int(6) not null,
    squad_value int(5) not null,
    total_national_trophies int(3) not null
)

added varchar(255)
```